# Apple Wallet (formerly Passbook) - Best way to add links

Tags: wallet

Does anyone have any experience with Apple Wallet (formerly Passbook) - I'm interested to know if it's possible to add hyperlinks on the reverse of the wallet?

It looks like you can simply add web addresses and apple auto applies a link tag to this but ideally I want to have the link address hidden behind the link title so it doesn't look messy?

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS7 you can add hyperlinks to the back of a pass and format the text that is displayed.

Simply add an `<a>` tag to the content of a field and the Apple Wallet app will render it as a clickable link.

For example: `<a href="http://www.developer.apple.com">Click here</a>`

If you do not use an `<a>` tag but include a valid URL the Apple Wallet app will display it as clickable address.